# Using db.allocate_id_range?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2, app-engine-ndb

The manual doesn't have an example how to use db.allocate_id_range. I tried some code and it failed, esxpecially for webapp2:s User model which is an ndb expando model. What I want to do is just create a User entity with an ID number of my choice so I try to use db.allocate_id_range but it is not working:

```
BadArgumentError: Expected an instance or iterable of (<class 'google.appengine.
ext.db.Model'>, <class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Key'>, <type 'bases
tring'>); received User<address=StringProperty('address'), auth_ids=StringProper
ty('auth_ids', repeated=True), created=DateTimeProperty('created', auto_now_add=
True), firstname=StringProperty('firstname'), lastname=StringProperty('lastname'
), notify=BooleanProperty('notify', default=False), notify_sms=BooleanProperty('
notify_sms', default=False), password=StringProperty('password'), phone_cell=Str
ingProperty('phone_cell'), registered=BooleanProperty('registered', default=Fals
e), sponsor=KeyProperty('sponsor'), updated=DateTimeProperty('updated', auto_now
=True)> (a MetaModel).
```

The way I try to do it is like this

`first_batch = db.allocate_id_range(User, 3001, 3001) #try allocate ID 3001`

Am I doing it wrong? I also tried putting the model name in quotes but that didn't work either. How should I be doing this? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's telling you that `User` is not a Model, but a MetaModel, whatever that is. What is it, and where is it coming from?

Comment: Which error do you get when putting the model name in quotes?

Comment: I've updated the NDB tutorial. It now contains a description of allocate_ids(). The cheat sheet also shows two allocate_ids() examples (one showing how to replace db.allocate_id_range().

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I just did `User(id=5005).put()` and the entities were created and I hope I don't have to worry about future collisions even though I created my entities assigning the numerical IDs manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `ndb.allocate_ids` function to achieve the same functionality.

If you compare [db.allocate_id_range](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py#709) and [ndb allocate_ids](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/context.py#707) implementation, you will see that they are both wrapper to the underlying datastore [allocate_ids](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py#1714) RPC.

If you want to mimic allocate_id_range with NDB you should be doing something like:

```
ctx = tasklets.get_context()
model.Key('Foo', 1) # the id(1) here is ingnored
start_id, end_id = ctx.allocate_ids(key, max=3001) # allocate all ids up to 3001
if start_id <= 3001:
    # it is safe to use 3001
    Foo(id=3001).put()
```

Or even simpler (like in the doc, guido pointed in the comment):

```
start_id, end_id = Foo.allocate_ids(max=3001)
if start_id <= 3001:
    Foo(id=3001).put()
```

Comment: Thanks it can create entities but it seems the ID I want cannot be allocated even though I cleared the datastore.

Comment: The ID allocator and the datastore really work independently, except when the datastore asks the ID allocator for a new ID.  All the ID allocator is telling you is that it will never return an ID <= end_id again.  You can now freely use the ID of your choice (3001), with the assurance that it won't be stomped on when you tell the datastore to get an ID for a new entity from the ID allocator.  So, basically, the "if start_id <= 3001:" test is unnecessary, assuming you have cleared the datastore.  (Clearing the datastore does not affect the ID allocator -- there is no way to reset the latter.)